# Dependency injection causing build to break

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on a project in which I need to use Http on the service layer. Below I am trying to inject Http in to the constructor as I normally would, however when trying to do `ionic build ios` I am getting the following errors:

```
[08:54:51]  Error: Error at /Users/zzz/Sites/angular-app/Test-Wondersign/.tmp/pages/home/home.ngfactory.ts:64:29 
[08:54:51]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. 
[08:54:51]  ngc failed 
[08:54:51]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[08:54:51]  Error: Error
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomeService } from '../home/home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [HomeService]
})
export class HomePage {

  users: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public hs: HomeService) {
    this.loadUsers();

  }

  loadUsers() {
    this.hs.getUsers().then( (response) => {
      this.users = JSON.parse(response._body);
    });
  }
}
```

home.service.ts

```
import { Http,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

export class HomeService {
    url:string;
    constructor(@Inject(Http) public http: Http) {
        this.url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'; 
    }

    getUsers(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            this.http.get(this.url).subscribe( result => {
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngFor="let user of users">
    {{ user.name}} {{ user.email}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: shouldn't HomeService be annotated with @Injectable too?

Comment: @toskv, thanks for the suggestion, you were right! that was exactly the issue.

Comment: I made an answer as well, please mark it as the correct one if that fixed it for you. :)

Comment: done, thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **HomeService** must be annotated with @Injectable.